# selectize.js typescript: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, configuration, selectize.js

I am trying to implement selectize.js inside my project with webpack and typescript.

First I installed selectize.js and related types:

```js
yarn add @selectize/selectize 
yarn add @types/select2
```

In my code I inserted this:

```js
require("selectize")();

jQuery(function($){

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.classic-select').selectize();
    
    });
    
});
```

The code compiles correctly but when I go to run it in console I get this error and I don't understand what it refers to:

```js
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

Can you help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance Danilo

Comment: By "run in the console", do you mean "run a command that starts a web server and look at the result in the browser"?

Comment: Hi @ChrisG Thank you for your reply. I mean to open the html page in the browser and verify that the code is interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several attempts, I figured out how to correctly implement selectize.

First I imported jquery and selectize like this:

```js
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'selectize'; // globally assign select2 fn to $ element
```

Next I used selectize

```js
jQuery(function($){

    $(document).ready(function(){

        (<any>$('.classic-select')).selectize();
    
    });
    
});
```

You can also implement it like this

```js
$(() => {
    (<any>$('.classic-select')).selectize();
});
```

If you compile the code the jquery library will also be imported. If jquery has already been called in your code you can exclude it from compiling through webpack:

```js
externals: {
  jquery: 'jQuery'
}
```

I hope it will be useful!

Comment: Thanks! it's working for me. Now I'm trying to use a plugin by importing it after selectize: `import "selectize-plugin-a11y";` and having this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Selectize is not defined" from the plugin js. Could you advise?

Comment: Hi @Khoait, I'm very sorry for only responding now but I really didn't see your comment. In your webpack configuration you should make these changes:

Add this : `const webpack = require('webpack');`

in plugins section add:

`new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            'window.$': 'jquery'
        })`

I solved it this way with some select2 plugins.